# On the Divergence of an Improper Integral where the Integrand becomes unbounded in the Neighbourhood of a Point inside the Interval of Integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indeterminate-forms

I have been having some trouble with the way to determine the convergence/divergence of an improper integral such as this: $$\int_0^a \frac{\arctan{(x)}}{1-x^3}dx,$$ where $a>1.$ It is evident that the integrand has an infinite discontinuity at $x=1,$ and the common course of action in order to establish the convergence/divergence of said integral would be to split the interval of integration at that point, and consider the two summands, both being improper integrals of their own, separately: $$\int_0^a \frac{\arctan{(x)}}{1-x^3}dx = \int_0^1 + \int_1^a.$$ However, both of the summands diverge, (for the integrand becomes infinite to the first order whatever side you approach $x=1$ from,) and they diverge into infinities of opposing signs. In short, this looks very much like an $\infty - \infty$ indeterminacy. Would it still be sound to say that the original integral diverges? This confusion is further facilitated by different textbooks. For instance, Courant and a bunch of others say we need to consider those „partial” improper integrals in complete separation, and if one diverges, I take it, the whole integral must diverge. Fichtenholtz, however, in his very influential „Course”, says the following:

> …in case all the summands exist, except for when two of them become infinite of different signs.

It is my own translation from the Russian, as I am aware that this textbook has yet to receive a complete English translation, but I think I have related the idea right. So, how should one go about splitting the interval like that? When two integrals, like in the case I mentioned, become infinite of different signs, are we to state confidently the divergence of the integral, or should we try to find another way that could potentially clear the indeterminacy?

Comment: The integral is divergent according to standard definition. But it is convergent in the so called principal value sense [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: It is unclear to me what Fichtenholtz is saying. That sentence fragment does not include enough to interpret his meaning. But if you are correct in asserting he claims the integral is convergent, then as Ryszard Szwarc says, he must be talking about the Cauchy Principle Value of the integral, which in your example will be the value $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^{1-h} + \int_{1+h}^a$$Note that the singularity is approached at the same rate on both sides, allowing the developing infinities to cancel out. Approaching at different rates would still diverge.